# How to use the try-except command in a for loop asking for user input?

Tags: for-loop, python-3.10

Abstract: I was making a guess the number game. Which will give you 7 tries to guess the no. after that it will tell you the number. I was trying to remove the human error of inputting a word(eg.six) instead of 6 by using Try and except method. This is how I wrote my code.

Tools: I am using Windows 10 with python 3.10.2 version in it.

Problem: I am facing an issue with try and except method which is not working. For eg. When I am typing six/five in words in user input its not printing `That is not a number`. Instead its giving me `Traceback error`. Which is what I am avoiding and trying to make a clean code.

```
    # This a guess the number game.


    import random  
    secretNumber=random.randint(1,20)

    for guessesTaken in range(1,7):
        print('Take a guess.')
        guess=int(input())

    #### Why this conditioning is importtant? ####
    #     Because it will only improve our guesses
        try:
            if guess < secretNumber:
                 print('Too Low')
            elif guess > secretNumber:
                 print('Too high')
            else:
                 break        #This is for the correct guess
        except:
            print('That is not a number')

    if guess == secretNumber:
        print('Good Game. '+'You guessed it correctly in '+ str(guessesTaken)+' 
    guesses')
    else:
         print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was '+str(secretNumber))
```

Comment: And how exactly is it "not working"? Is there an error message or some unexpected behaviour? But for starters: you may want to put the statement that might raise an exception (ie `guess=int(input()`) *inside*  the `try:` block

Comment: Thanks its working. Now I need to uuderstand why. This is my first time I am learning coding language.

Comment: What do you mean by "why"? The `try: ... except:` only catches exceptions that happen inside the block .. In your code the exception happened outside ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

input throws error before try block , move input() into try block

```
    # This a guess the number game.


    import random  
    secretNumber=random.randint(1,20)

    for guessesTaken in range(1,7):
        print('Take a guess.')
 

    #### Why this conditioning is importtant? ####
    #     Because it will only improve our guesses
        try:
            guess=int(input())
            if guess < secretNumber:
                 print('Too Low')
            elif guess > secretNumber:
                 print('Too high')
            else:
                 break        #This is for the correct guess
        except:
            print('That is not a number')

    if guess == secretNumber:
        print('Good Game. '+'You guessed it correctly in '+ str(guessesTaken)+' 
    guesses')
    else:
         print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was '+str(secretNumber))
```